# setting variables with before_filter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have one class FogsController, that have one filter and two functions

```
class FogsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_id, only: [:get_orders]

  def get_orders
    #doing some condition with variable **@name**
  end

  def call_orders
    #calling get_orders here
  end

  protected

  def check_id
   @name = params[:name]
   #checking some condition with that **@name**
  end

end
```

So what I am trying to do is, I need to call **get_orders** function from **call_orders**. So the issue here is for the normal call to function **get_orders**, before the function **check_id** will trigger and set variables. So how does this before_filter function work when I am calling the **get_orders** from **call_orders** method?

Answer (score 1):

The filter is called after the controller is initialized. So if you call any action from another action, the filter will not be executed.

So in this case `check_id` will be called only once.

Answer (score 1):

Filters work only on the basis of what action is routed to your controller. Internally there is a method called `process_action` that (among other things) executes callbacks for that action. and the action itself. However if you call actions from other actions then this won't trigger any callbacks.

Typically I would recommend that you don't do this - refactor your code so that both `get_orders` and `call_orders` call a private method that does this common bit of work (including setting @name).

Comment: So whats the better way to setting all these variables before that function call? is process_action

Comment: no - that's a rails internal. I'll add an alternative

Comment: ya, actually i tried around the same way, but when i call that get_orders from call_order , the params have new values, so i need to pass the new params, in that call i got issues